# Solución error: ttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Tengo el siguiente codigo que permite visualizar una imagen en tkinter:

```
 imageIco=Image.open('rsc/ico_perfil1.png')
        imgIco=imageIco.resize((190,190))
        ico_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgIco)
```

El problema es que me da el siguiente error:

> ttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Anteriormente funcionaba de esa manera y no he modificado ese fragmento de código.
Alguna solución?. Tengo varios modulos, pero eso creo que no será el problema, ya que funcionaba y no daba error.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Todo depende de cómo esté definido en ese momento el símbolo `Image`. Se supone que debería ser una clase o módulo importado de algún paquete. Probablemente con algo como `from PIL import Image`. Pero si tu código ha redefinido el símbolo `Image` en alguna otra parte (por ejemplo, haciendo algo como `Image = "prueba.png"`) entonces cabe esperar todo tipo de problemas como el que presentas. Puedes "depurar" el código haciendo justo antes un `print(Image)` o `print(type(Image))` a ver qué sale.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Lo solucione importando los módulos en diferente orden. no se si tiene algo que ver pero funcionó.

Comment: Solo por suponer algo, es probable que la causa sea que tienes una linea como `from PIL import Image` seguido de `from otromodulo import Image` o `from otromodulo import *`. Entonces, el objeto Image de `otromodulo` reemplaza al de PIL. Si este es el caso, te podría surgir otro problema si es que querés usar el objeto Image de `otromodulo`. Si querés una respuesta más detallada y acertada para poder aprender mejor, te recomiendo leer el link que te pasó HeytalePazguato y editar tu pregunta. Recuerda ayudarnos a ayudarte.